# Usage, Meaning Of "Around"

Tags: prepositions, figurative-language

I have a question about the preposition "*around*" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arleigh_Burke-class_destroyer):

> The Arleigh Burke-class of guided missile destroyers (DDGs) is the United States Navy's first class of destroyer built ***around*** the Aegis Combat System and the SPY-1D multi-function phased array radar.

Does "*around*" mean the outer shell of the ship is "*around*" the Aegis Combat System and SPY-1D multi-function phased array radar?

Comment: It's a *figurative* usage, not a spatial one. It would still be valid if the ACS / SPY-1D hardware were fully contained in a raft towed by the destroyer, since what's being said is that *conceptually* the *building/designing* of DDGs "flows from" and incorporates those pre-existing systems, regardless of the physical disposition of the components in the final product.

Answer (score 3):

In this case they are saying that the ship's main purpose was to carry the ACS and SPY-1D.
The pertinent definition (From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/around)):

> ***around:***
>   7.  In such a way as to have a basis or center in: *an economy focused around farming and light industry.*

In other words the ship was designed by looking at the desired systems to determine their requirements and the ship's design was created to reflect that. For example if the ACS required a platform with stability control and width of 58 feet, then the ship designers said, "Ok, our ship must have a stability control system and a width of 58 feet and then derived other requirements from there."